# IBM-Watson Text to Speech throws "403:Forbidden" Error

Tags: python, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to use IBM watson api for text to speech service. The service works if I use curl command but when I try to use the srrvice using Python SDK, It throws me below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 234, in send
>       response.status_code, error_message, http_response=response)
>   ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: Forbidden, Code: 403
>   Method failed with status code 403: Forbidden

Below is the curl command

```
curl -X GET -u "apikey:myapiKey" --output hello_world.wav "https://api.eu-de.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?accept=audio/wav&text=Hallo%20Welt&voice=de-DE_DieterVoice"
```

Below is the python code

```
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator


from ibm_watson import ApiException
import json

IBM_API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.eu-de.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize"


IBM_TTS_API_KEY = "myAPIKey"

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(IBM_TTS_API_KEY)
text_to_speech = TextToSpeechV1(authenticator=authenticator)
text_to_speech.set_service_url(IBM_API_ENDPOINT)


try:
    with open('IBM.wav', 'wb') as audio_file:
        audio_file.write(text_to_speech.synthesize("Hallo world", voice='de-DE_DieterVoice', accept='audio/wav').get_result().content)

except ApiException as ex:
    print("Method failed with status code " + str(ex.code) + ": " + ex.message)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the Current usage ( of 10000 Thousand char). I had the same issue when I reached the maximum limit of characters per month.

( Thousand char: Using 21091 of 10000)

Comment: Yes, I also think that this issue arises when the maximum limit is crossed.

Answer (score 1):

This will because you are are tacking the method and the version at the end of the endpoint. As you are using the Python SDK for IBM-Watson the SDK take care of applying the method when you invoke `synthesize`. Consequently your endpoint should only be:

```py
IBM_API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.eu-de.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com"
```

Check the API documentation for further details - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech/text-to-speech?code=python#service-endpoint

Comment: Even after changing the "IBM_API_ENDPOINT" as suggested above , I get below error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 234, in send
    response.status_code, error_message, http_response=response)
ibm_cloud_sdk_core.api_exception.ApiException: Error: Forbidden, Code: 403
Method failed with status code 403: Forbidden

Comment: When you check your credentials on IBM cloud, what does the endpoint show up as? That is what you should be using!